# Diagonalisation of this simple variant of the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

is it possible to diagonalise the Hamiltonian
$$
H = A (a + a^\dagger) + B a^\dagger a \;,
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some nonzero real constants?

Comment: Hint: write it in terms of $x$ and $p$ or, alternatively, $b^\dagger=\sqrt{B}(a^\dagger+\alpha)$ for some constant $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you @ZeroTheHero, am I allowed to add a constant in the Bogolyubov transformation? What is the meaning of this translation? if any

Comment: If you write $H$ in terms of $x$ and $p$, and complete the square, you should see where the shift comes from.